# Delphi XE2, how to keep form ON TOP after changing VCL styles

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I encountered a weird issue with XE2:

I'm using HWND_TOPMOST with SetWindowPos to set my form on top, but if I switch VCL styles at runtime, the window isn't topmost anymore, and unsetting/re-setting it doesn't fix it either.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  You should report this to [QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/).

Comment: @MasonWheeler this is not a bug, this is the way how the vcl styles works, every time which you change a vcl style the handle of the forms is recreated.

Comment: @RRUZ: Based on the OP's original description, that re-setting the attribute didn't work with styles on, that would certainly be a bug if it was true.  (See the OP's comment to Sertac's answer for a better explanation of what was really happening.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that the form is being recreated because of a style change and loosing its top most style since the VCL have no knowledge of this. Either use:

```
FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
```

or override `CreateWindowHandle` so that `SetWindowPos` is called each time the form is recreated:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  protected
    procedure CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams); override;
  ..

procedure TForm1.CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE);
end;
```

BTW, I couldn't duplicate *"unsetting/re-setting doesn't fix it"*. With my tests, calling `SetWindowPos` again fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, re-setting it actually works. The issue was that the window handle was different because I call RecreateWnd after changing VCL styles to overcome a different issue, so I was calling SetWindowPos with a now invalid handle.

Answer (score 5):

Setting a new style on a control causes the control's window handle to be recreated, thus `HWND_TOPMOST` would have to be re-applied again.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search on the internet and in Delphi help with no solution, I tried several different codes, several tips, all of them with no effect whatsoever, the problem persisted. Looking at the help, I decided to test the simple code below that worked perfectly for me.

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.RestoreTopMosts;
end;
```